# Laravel\Passport\Passport is not defined

Tags: laravel, undefined, laravel-passport

I have installed Laravel passport using composer however when I try to import it in AuthServiceProvider it shows that the path is not defined
Can anyone help, please?

```
    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
   // App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    Laravel\Passport\Passport::class,


],
```

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
         'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

```
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();

}
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the exact error message and the related code to your question please?

Comment: you must share more details

Comment: I have added the code of app.php config file, the last line gives undefined error

Answer (score 0):

It is working now I have installed the following package:

```
composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge
```